# Can CakePHP model names contain numbers?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a model called `Stage1Application` and a corresponding controller called `Stage1ApplicationsController`.

In the controller when I use

```
$this->Stage1Application->create();
```

I get "called create on non-object" error.  Is this because I have numbers in the names of my model/controller?

I also have the line

```
public $uses = array('Package','PersonalDetail','MarriageDetail','ChildrenDetail');
```

at the beginning of my controller - is this stopping it from including its own model?
If this is the problem then how do I make the `$uses` array append - so that the model for the current controller is included by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any limitations to model names other than they must be a valid class name.  From PHP's manual: A valid class name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php  So, numbers should be allowed, as long as you don't start with a number.

And yes, if you declare $uses, it overwrites the default $uses property.  Either add `Stage1Application` to your $uses property declaration:

```
public $uses = array('Package','PersonalDetail','MarriageDetail','ChildrenDetail', 'Stage1Application');
```

Or, you can alter your `$uses` property in the controller's `beforeFilter` function and have the models still load:

```
$this->uses = array_merge($this->uses, array('Package','PersonalDetail','MarriageDetail','ChildrenDetail'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the Stage1 model in your uses array, that is why you get that error.

Comment: thanks, is there any way of stating the uses array such that Cake automatically includes the related model for the controller and simply appends any extras I want?